# Cannot get information generated from google maps into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am trying to insert values for longitude, latitude and descriptions of locations generated from google maps (the ID value is to be generated within PhpMyAdmin.  When I run the following code I always get the "error" message. If I "echo $sql;" before //insert values into database then I get the intended output so I guess it must be a problem with transferring to the database.

I'm using phpMyAdmin from within MAMP so am not sure if that is causing any issues of whether I'm missing something obvious in the code?  I'm fairly new to PHP so may have missed something obvious! Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "googlemaps") or die("could not connent to db");
error_reporting(0);

for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['value']);$i=$i+3)
{
    $sql .= "(NULL, '".$_POST['value'][$i]."', '".$_POST['value'][$i+1]."', '".$_POST['value'][$i+2]."'),";
}

//remove last comma
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1);


//insert values into database
$query = "INSERT INTO 'googlemaps'.'values' ('id', 'lat', 'lng', 'des') VALUES " .$sql;

$status = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if($status)
    echo "inserted";
else
    echo "error";

?>
```

Comment: What is the "error" ?

Comment: Your table and columns should not be wrapped in quotes; that's your main problem if not "thee" problem. Either remove them, or use backticks. Plus, you're using the word `values` for your table alias, now THAT must be wrapped in backticks since it's a [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: What is the value of $sql?

Comment: How about echoing the $query. Do you get what is intended?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. Fred -ii- it still wouldn't work after changing the values ' to ` but then I changed the $status to $enter and it worked for some reason!

Comment: what $enter, wher you get that in your code??